# Where to save the video files Cache memory or external memory?

Tags: android, caching, video, android-external-storage

I am working on a video based android application in which i am playing videos from server using videoview and i want to cache those videos for which i am downloading the video first and saving them into external storage as an temp file ,So can anybody guide me is it good approach to store those video files in external storage or i should save it into cache memory of the app?

Comment: Saving it in a SD card would be a good idea, otherwise app size will be increased for every time you downloading the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to cache files externally, you could use `getExternalCacheDir()`. For other options, check out this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html.

It does, however, mean that you have to delete files that aren't in use manually.

Comment: then what is the difference between saving in sdcard or getExternalCacheDir();

Comment: Saving it externally gives other applications and the user read access to it.